# AngularJS ng-model binding with numerical value

Tags: angularjs

In angularJs ng-model i m binding with some name with ++ operator like

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <input type="text" ng-model="firstname++hkjnh">
    {{firstname+" "+lastname}}
</div>
```

output -> FirstName0 
from where 0 comes in text

or

```
  <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
        <input type="text" ng-model="+124343">
        {{firstname+" "+lastname}}
    </div>
```

output ->124343

so plese tell me how angular work with these type of things

Comment: can u share executable code?

Answer (score 1):

ng-model directive we are using for two way binding. That's just a variable, we can get corresponding value in controller. Refer

https://plnkr.co/edit/AEblZEuiEL8mzvsFoz8M?p=preview

```
angular.module('inputExample', [])
.controller('ExampleController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
   $scope.val++a = '1';
}]);

<input ng-model="val++a" ng-pattern="/^\d+$/" name="anim" class="my-input"
     aria-describedby="inputDescription" />
```

Answer (score 0):

ng-model="firstname++hkjnh" trying to create an variable with controller as  $scope.firstname++hkjnh, since in js variable name can't hold any type of operator it will generate an error.

here ++ operator trying to evaluate with RHS value which is undefined,hence model value will be uncertain(varies on machine to machine).

In 2nd case model just evaluate the value(only with numeric value).